# Create modules for Linux install of PocketSphinx?

Tags: python, python-3.4, pocketsphinx

I am trying to get Python 3.4 working with PocketSphinx on a Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 OS) machine.  Yesterday, I successfully installed both `sphinxbase-5prealpha` and `pocketsphinx-5prealpha`.  I confirmed my install by successfully running `pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes`

I'm trying to move on to the Python API for but can't find the python modules (`sphinxbase` and `pocketsphinx`) anywhere in my directories.  I searched the web but can only find references to installing/creating a `pocketsphinx` file as relates to Windows install.

How do I create modules `sphinxbase` and `pocketsphinx` in my Linux installation?  And where should they live in relation to `../MySphinxDirectory`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the python modules for `pocketsphinx` and `sphinxbase` through pip.

**Just run:**

```
sudo pip install pocketsphinx
```

The `sphinxbase` module is a requirement of `pocketsphinx` so it will be installed automatically when you install the `pocketsphinx` package.

Then in your python program, you should be able to import modules from them using:

```
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import ...
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import ...
```

The [pocketsphinx repository](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx) includes [an example you can test with](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/c5f43e873d4cadc6e1af73b558950bd7e88c78b4/swig/python/test/kws_test.py) if you do not already have one.